# PHPMailer to send email address verification email not working

Tags: mysql, phpmailer

I‘d like to send a verification email for new account. Everything works fine on my local environment. But if I try to do it on the remote server, I got a problem. Inside the email there is the verification link for the user. Instantly, when the email is sent, this link is processed. That means, the verification has been done without clicking the link.
My search through the Internet was not successful. Is there anyone who can help me by solving my problem?
Best regards
Joachim Schmaeck

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: There is an email client somewhere in the world which is constantly checking the given mailbox for new emails and if it finds one - it parses the content and tries to fetch all the URLs it finds. You should find and destroy this email client - or use another mailbox on different domain/provider. Or it could be a browser extension.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for your good hint IVO GELOV. All my emails pass a security gate: Trend Micro. May be that is the place where the implemented links will be fetched.
Tomorrow I will have a discussion with my system admin to check it. In the meantime, I will try to use the Google mail account to check if the error also happened.

Comment: It’s common for mail servers to open every link in a message to check for malware. The solution is to not take action on that initial click, but require a second one to confirm the action.

Comment: I didn‘t find a good solution to my question. I was not able to use the email template with an anchor tag without the described problem.
I decide to do it another way. My solution:
I check the time between sending the email and receiving the verification with the MySQL. Only if more than 30 seconds are expired the verification is acceptable. For me it works.